# Terrain Generation with Realistic Height Map

Tags: procedural-generation, heightmap

I am having troubles finding out the best way to add realism to a terrain generator. At this point I have a flood fill that works perfectly, however if I want to add any sort of realism I will need to add in height variables. I have seen the following methods attempted to make heightmaps:

- Tectonic Plates https://experilous.com/1/blog/post/procedural-planet-generation
- Simplex/Perlin Noise
- Diamond-Square Algoritm

Right now I am generating plates through my flood fill, but I am not sure where to go from there.

I am not sure about using a noise function just due to the fact that I would need to generate biomes within a continent to make it look realistic (A continent with just mountains would be unrealistic). The diamond square algorithm probably isn't going to work for my needs because I would like to be flexible in sizing.

What is my best option for generating a height map if I have square tiles to give some realism, not very resource intensive, and keep the code I have?

Here is an image of the generation, and the generation code is in the Github project:
https://github.com/Hunterb9101/TileWorkspace/blob/59fe1f28f019d7128c970772d1ef6bd30d63072c/Generation.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tldr:** I would use a perlin noise generation with some tacked on biomes.

This [article/tutorial](http://www.redblobgames.com/maps/terrain-from-noise/) goes over code snippets and their implementation methods. Suggesting the *best* algorithm for your task depends entirely on your skill and end result goals.

However a brief description of perlin noise and using it with realistic aims in mind...

> As with most terrain generation, noise functions are your friend -
>   Perlin and/or simplex noise in particular. I've implemented some
>   planetary terrain generation algorithms and although they are in 2d,
>   the resulting height / "texture" map could be projected to a sphere
>   rather easily. I assume conversion to hex format is not an issue
>   either.
>
> My technique has been creating multiple noise layers, e.g. temperature
>   and humidity. Temperature is fused with a latitude coordinate, in
>   order to make the equator more hot and poles cold, while the noise
>   makes sure it's not a simple gradient. The final terrain type is
>   selected by rules like "if hot and not humid then pick desert". You
>   can see my JavaScript implementation of this here:
>   https://github.com/tapio/infiniverse/blob/master/js/universe/planet-aerial.js
>
> As for the water percentage, you can just adjust the water level
>   height as noise functions tend to have a constant average. Another
>   option is to apply an exponent filter (useful also when generating
>   clouds, see my implementation here).
>
> Another way to generate spherical terrain that came into mind (haven't
>   tested) is to use 3d noise and sample it from a surface of a sphere,
>   using the resulting value as the ground height at that point. You can
>   then weight that according to amount of water on planet and the
>   latitude coordinate.
>
> I'll end with a link to one practical implementation of 3d planetary
>   terrain generation:
>   http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/tutorials/tutorial8.html

To generate any random style of realistic terrain you are going to have to use noise of some kind. In past projects I myself have used the diamond square algorithm. However that was to simply generate heightmaps.

For some more light reading I would check out [this](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/generating-realistic-terrain/184409269) article about realistic terrain techniques.